# Integer with 24 digits

Tags: c#, biginteger

To check some bank account numbers I want to do a modulo 97 on an account number.
But a lot of account number is to big to enter in a UInt64.

How can I do an opperation on a 24 digits integer ?

Thanks,

Sample code (it can't convert) :

```
(Convert.ToUInt64("756842356987456214536254") % 97 == 1);
```

Comment: A side note: it's probably bad idea to store bank account number as number... It's not really a mathematical number, it's more like car register plate id. At least in some places in the world, bank account may have letters, and/or may have dashes and/or removable zeros in the middle (like 11-22 is same as 000011-0000000022).

Comment: I have to use it as a number. Because the IBAN standard to check the validity of a bank account. To do this, we must transform the letters of the account number and then perform a mathematical opperation. Watch: # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number Validating_the_IBAN

Comment: Ah, that's good trivia to know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way would be to use `System.Numeric`'s [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx):

```
BigInteger bi = BigInteger.Parse("756842356987456214536254");
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks,

It's work.

```
Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("756842356987456214536254");

(Convert.ToInt32(bi.Mod(new BigInteger("97")).ToString()) == 1);
```

Comment: You don't see it with BigInt ?
Itcompile for me.
I use Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger

Comment: You shouldn't comment on a post by posting a new answer. Please add a comment on the relevant post. Answers are not displayed chronologically, so it's clear which answer you are responding to.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers have at most 28 digits, you can also use `decimal`. This might be more convenient to use than `BigInteger`.

Comment: Yes, but some account numbers have more than 28 digits. So, I will use BigInteger because it can have at most 38 digits.

Answer (score -1):

If the input is text it could be easier to take the string and use the [Encoding.GetBytes method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) so you get a byte array that can be passed to [BigInteger constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) like this example:

```
var enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
var bi = new BigInteger(enc.GetBytes("756842356987456214536254"));
var result = (bi % 97).ToString();
```

Comment: This does not make any sense to me: `BigInteger(byte[])` is expecting a number in binary representation, not an array of UTF-8 characters!