# How to divide by a 22-digit number in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to develop a software for a project at my university and I encountered a problem. I need to divide a double variable to a number of 22-digits length in C#. Is this possible?

Below is the brief code of the main operation:

```
public double Chi_Square
    {
        get
        {
            double sus =NumWords * Math.Pow((Array2BY2["O11"] * Array2BY2["O12"]) - (Array2BY2["O12"] * Array2BY2["O21"]), 2);
            long jos = (Array2BY2["O11"] + Array2BY2["O12"]) * (Array2BY2["O11"] + Array2BY2["O21"]) * (Array2BY2["O12"] + Array2BY2["O22"]) * (Array2BY2["O21"] + Array2BY2["O22"]);
            double result = sus / (double)jos;
            return result;
        }
    }
```

NumWords is of type int.
Array2BY2 is a Dictionary

In the variable `sus`, I get the required result as I have checked this in Excel. I just need the double result of this division.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your actual problem here?

Comment: Take a look at [decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx), or the [System.Numerics Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics(v=vs.110).aspx); maybe [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) can be of help. There are also plenty of "math libraries"; head over to [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org) and [find one that suits your needs](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=math).

Comment: i don't know what is you'r actual problem... i think is the double type size limitation so you can try using decimal instead double

Comment: use  [BigInteger](http://fahadjameel.com/2015/06/24/how-to-use-large-numbers-in-c/) for very large numbers

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508858/integer-with-24-digits?

Comment: Guys, BigInteger is for **integers** - this is a chi squared calculation, which is naturally going to be a floating point number.  Decimal is not likely to have sufficient order of magnitude to deal with scientific calculations.  The real question here is - *Do you really need 22 decimal places of accuracy?*.  My feeling is probably no - whatever you are calculating a chi-squared for, you are almost never going to be 22 decimal places certain about the input data so you don't need 22 decimal places of accuracy in the result.  Just use `double` and be done with it.

Comment: @J...: Here's pi: 3.14159265359, here's pi again as an integer: 314159265359. Aside the decimal point: what's the difference? If you keep track of where the decimal point should be there's no real difference between floating point + integer (in the real world, I'm not talking about how they're implemented in your computer). So you can easily use BigInteger for this calculation if you want to; it's called "[Fixed-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic)". It's like storing a product price in cents (always integer) instead of in dollars+cents (rational number).

Comment: ...and continuing my above comment: It is, indeed, very likely 22 decimal places is waaay to precise for any real practical purpose ([even NASA uses 'only' 15/16 digits of precision](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/observations/how-much-pi-do-you-need/) to keep the ISS operational) and aodpi should, probably, look into my other suggestion(s) as well: stop reinventing the wheel and use a suited library.

Comment: @RobIII `BigInteger` does not implement fixed point arithmetic.  If you divide two `BigInteger`s, you get a `BigInteger` as a result.  While I agree you can *use* `BigIntegers` as an ingredient in an arbitrary (dare I say even ad-hoc) fixed-point arithmetic engine, it does not provide this functionality by default.  The *"keeping track of the decimal place"* problem would still be left up to the user.

Comment: Thanks guys, i managed to solve my issue using decimal as @RobIII suggested. Have a nice day.